# Auto resize window with form and html component

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to create a popup window, which will include a form and buttons. Because I want to add some custom styling, I've added a div at the top of the window (creating a new component) and inserted it to window items. The problem is that this div takes the whole height of my window, and nothing apart of css height rules with `!important` suffix work. I've tried adding `style: {height: 45}` to autoEl definition, setting height of the component but without success. When using the css though my form (with autoHeight: true) doesn't fit in the window as it's lacking those 45 pixels and is hidden by the buttons.

Here's my window definition.

```
Ext.define('Dialog', {
    extend : 'Ext.window.Window',    
    modal : false,
    width : 240,
    cls: 'sch-pdfexportdialog',
    frame : false,
    header : false,
    title : null,
    layout : 'fit',
    draggable : true,
    padding: 0,

    autoHeight: true,
    headerTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
            '<h4>{headerText}</h4>'+
            '<span id="close"></span>'
    ),

    initComponent: function () {
        var me        = this;

        Ext.apply(this, {
            items : [
                me.createHeader(),
                me.formPanel
            ],
            fbar : {
                xtype: 'button',
                scale: 'medium',
                text: this.cancelButtonText,
                handler: function() {
                    this.hideDialog();
                },
                scope: this
            }          
        });  

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    createHeader: function () {
        var me = this;

        return new Ext.Component({
            autoEl: { 
                tag: 'div', 
                cls: 'sch-pdfexportdialog-header', 
                html: me.headerTpl.apply({ headerText: me.dialogHeader })
            }
        });
    }
})
```

This is how it looks right now :

[image: current state of dialog]

I've fixed it temporarily with adding a listener on 'resize' event of the form and updating height of the dialog by those missing 45px, but I'd like to make it cleaner.

---

EDIT

I've modified the component a bit, to use Ext.panel.Header, but this gives me 'container is null' error in ext's 'initContainer' method :/

```
Ext.define('Dialog', {
    extend : 'Ext.window.Window',    
    modal : false,
    width : 240,
    frame : false,
    header : false,
    title : null,
    layout : 'fit',
    draggable : true,
    padding: 0,

    autoHeight: true,
    headerTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<h4>{headerText}</h4>',
            '<span id="{id}-btnClose"></span>'
    ),
    headerText: 'Foo',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me        = this;

        Ext.apply(this, {
            header: me.createHeader(),
            items : [
                me.formPanel
            ],
            fbar : {
                xtype: 'button',
                scale: 'medium',
                text: this.cancelButtonText,
                handler: function() {
                    this.hideDialog();
                },
                scope: this
            }          
        });  

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    createHeader: function () {
        var me = this;

        return {
            renderTpl: me.headerTpl,
            renderData: {
                headerText: me.headerText
            },
            childEls: ["btnClose"]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you looked at extending `Ext.panel.Header`, or at least applying your styling to the header directly?

Comment: I'll check that, thanks.

Comment: nope, this one bring up an error :/